# Windows Virtual (fake) Device INF installation

Tags: windows, installation, driver, virtual, inf

I have been trying to install the MSVAD virtual audio sample drivers from the Windows DDK on Windows 7 64bits, without success.
I modified the sample INF to only support the "simple" driver. The ChkInf tool confirms that everything is OK with the INF file, I signed the package with a Test certificate. So far, so good.
The problem is: despite reading the documentation on the Microsoft website, I have no clue of how to actually install this driver. The problem is that it does not match a physical device, so I can't use the Device Manager to update the driver on an existing device.
Aside from that, the right-click on INF + Install method does not work as the INF lacks a DefaultInstall section (which is a requirement for signing drivers).

I would like to be able to install this driver from the command-line ideally, but if a specific program is required, I'll have to go that way.

Thanks in advance for any clue on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess I hadn't searched far enough: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowspro-audiodevelopment/thread/68ac63f3-7bb1-45b0-9677-957d7aa9f2d9